# How does the inheritance of static variables and their values work?

Tags: java, inheritance, static-variables

I have this piece of code and my question is, if the value of the static variable z is "shared" among the subclass(es)? Concrete: When I declare `b` does this mean that first the constructor of A is used and passes the modified values of z to the constructor of B?

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    A a = new A();
    System.out.println("A: " + a.x);
    a.print();

    A b = new B();
    System.out.println("B: " + b.x);
    a.print();
  }
}

public class A {
  public static int z; // default: 0
  public int x = 10;

  public A() {
    x++;
    z++; // z = 1
  }

  print(){
    System.out.println("A: "+ x);
    System.out.println("A: "+ ++z); // z = 2
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  public int x = 100;

  public B() {
    x++;
    z++;   //z is not 3. z = 4 (because of the constructor of A that 
                                uses the modified values of z?)
  }

  public void print() {
    System.out.println("B: "+ x);
    System.out.println("B: "+ ++z); // z = 5
  }
}
```

The output is :

> A: 11 A: 11 A: 2 B: 11 B: 102 B: 5

Are these values passed to the subclass because z is static and that means if I change its values they will be changed while running my code if i don't change z by passing it another concrete value in A?

I am confused. Hopefully somebody can explain this to me.

Comment: There is no inheritance involved: it is the same field

Comment: You would know what happens if you used uour debugger to step through the code, line by line, or if you simply added println() logs to the code.

Comment: The output should be A: 11 A: 11 A: 2 B: 11 B: 101 B: 5. There are two topics you need understsand: 1. order of initialization and instantiation. 2. field hiding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *if the value of the static variable z is "shared" among the subclass(es)?*

Yes. `static` variables are class level variables, meaning they do not belong to an instance of a class but to the class itself. They are accessible from a child class as long as they are not declared private, and they are not inherited. There's only one `static` variable for all instances of the class regardless if it's an instance of the class itself or an instance of any of its sub-classes. Thus:

```
A.z = 5; // z is 5 now
B.z = 7; // z is 7 now 
System.out.prinln(A.z); // will print 7 since there's only one z shared by everybody
                        // remember, z belongs to A not to an instance of A.
```

> *When I declare b does this mean that first the constructor of A is used and passes the modified values of z to the constructor of B?*

Not quite. Before a child class is constructed, its parent class needs to be constructed. How can you extend something that doesn't exist =]? Thus a call to the parent constructor is made before any other instruction in the child constructor.

```
public B() {
    x++;
    z++
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public B() {
    super(); // initialize A before initializing B
    x++;
    z++
}
```

If you don't call `super()` explicitly, which unless you need to pass something to the parent constructor you don't have to, the compiler will insert `super()` for you. So in the `B` constructor, the constructor for `A` is called but it doesn't pass `z` to `B` it just does what you instructed it to do and moves on.

Comment: Thank you StaticBeagle for this really useful comment! I think I understand the concept now better...

Comment: @MelTorment you bet, glad I could help!